# Chart.js styling questions

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to style a chart.js graph and have tried everything in the documentation but just cant figure it out,

I want to recolour the grid lines and font,
and also reduce the thickness of the data line and remove the circles on the data points,
as it starts to get very cluttered looking when I feed it the data.
Any ideas? Thanks

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            showGraph();
        });


        function showGraph()
        {
            {
                $.post("data.php",
                function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    var time = [];
                    var s1 = [];
                    var s1price = [];

                    for (var i in data) {
                        time.push(data[i].time);
                        s1.push(data[i].s1);
                        s1price.push(data[i].s1price);

                        
                    }
                    



                    var chartdata = {
                        labels: time,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'price',
                                backgroundColor: '#1C00ff00',
                                borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                                labelColor:'#ffffff',
                                data: s1price
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    var graphTarget = $("#graphCanvas");

                    var c = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: chartdata
                    });
                      var chartdata2 = {
                        labels: time,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'price',
                                backgroundColor: '#1C00ff00',
                                borderColor: '#cc0000',
                                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                                
                                data: s1
                            }
                            
                        ]
                    };

                    var graphTarget2 = $("#graphCanvas2");

                    var c = new Chart(graphTarget2, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: chartdata2,
                        
                    });
                });
                
                }
                }
                

        
        
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As described here in the docs you can see you can color the `gridLines` for example: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration.

Please take a second good look at the documentation and the examples (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/bar/vertical.html) because everything you wanted is documented and most things are also in examples

Live example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      radius: 0
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          color: 'yellow'
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'blue'
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          color: 'purple'
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'green'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```